# Как удалить элемент из списка ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

Не получается удалить выбранный элемент из списка ListView. Пробую делать следующим образом, но программа просто зависает и вылетает. Делаю следующим образом:

```
<ListView Name="UsersListView" SelectionChanged="Button_ClickSelectUser">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

В самом классе выполняю следующую процедуру

```
public partial class Users : UserControl {

    ObservableCollection<User> users;

    ...

    private void Button_ClickSelectUser(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        users.RemoveAt(UsersListView.SelectedIndex);
        UsersListView.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

При выборе элемента из ListView программа вылетает. Понимаю, что делаю что-то не так, но не могу понять, что именно?

UPD:

Я получаю список пользователей в JSON с удаленного сервера, после чего формирую из них UI ListView. Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на пользователя, элемент из списка удалялся (в UI ListView).

```
namespace WpfApp1 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        
        ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        User SelectedUser { get; }

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            getAllUsers();
        }

        async Task getAllUsers() {
            var response = await Task.Run(() => {
                return "[{\"id\":1,\"username\":\"demo\"},{\"id\":2,\"username\":\"test\"}]";
            });

            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<User>>(response);
            UsersListView.ItemsSource = data;

        }

        private void Button_ClickSelectUser(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            users.RemoveAt(UsersListView.SelectedIndex);
        }

    }
}
```

Без использования MVVM.

Comment: Без текста ошибки это угадайка. В вопросе не видно как users биндится к UsersListView, да и при использовании биндинга прямо лезть к UsersListView никогда не нужно, то есть ` UsersListView.Items.Refresh();` никто не использует

Comment: Ошибки в консоле не наблюдал

Comment: `ItemsSource = data`, `users.RemoveAt` - вас точно ничего не смущает?